# Add a new table with different sqlhelper class file in helper in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I have already created a database and a table in it. Now I want to add another table in the database with new table in it.

```html
package com.example.user.shopkeeper.sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.user.shopkeeper.model.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "manager.db";
        private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

        private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
        private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
        private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
        private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";
        private static final String COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER = "user_mobile_number";

        private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT, "+  COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT" + ")";

        private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
            db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void addUser(User user){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME,user.getName());
            values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,user.getEmail());
            values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD,user.getPassword());
            values.put(COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER,user.getNumber());

            db.insert(TABLE_USER,null,values);
            db.close();
        }

        public boolean checkUser(String email, String password){
            String[] columns = {
                    COLUMN_USER_ID
            };

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ? ";
            String[] selectionArgs = {email , password};

            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                    columns,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null );

            int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            if(cursorCount > 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        }


        public boolean checkUser(String email){
            String[] columns = {
                    COLUMN_USER_ID
            };

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" ;
            String[] selectionArgs = {email};

            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                    columns,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null );

            int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            if(cursorCount > 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        }

        public List<String> getContactNumber(String email){
            List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] contact = new String[]{email};
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER +", " + COLUMN_USER_ID + ", " +COLUMN_USER_NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " =?";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, contact);

            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                a.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER)));
                a.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NAME)));
                a.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID)));

            }

            db.close();
            c.close();
            return a;
        }

}
```

Another one is:-

```html
package com.example.user.shopkeeper.sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

import com.example.user.shopkeeper.model.User;

public class AddClientUser extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns{


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "manager.db";

    private final static String TABLE_CLIENT = "clients";
    private final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    private final static String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private final static String CLIENT_USER_ID = "client_user_id";
    private final static String COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME = "name";
    private final static String COLUMN_CLIENT_GENDER = "gender";
    private final static String COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_number";
    private final static String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public final static int GENDER_UNKNOWN = 0;
    public final static int GENDER_MALE = 1;
    public final static int GENDER_FEMALE = 2;

    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CLIENT + "( "
            + CLIENT_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_CLIENT_GENDER + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER" + " )";



    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CLIENT;

    public AddClientUser(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean checkUserMobile(String contact){
        String[] columns = {
                CLIENT_USER_ID
        };

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER  + " =? ";
        String[] selectionArgs = {contact};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CLIENT,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null );

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if(count > 0){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addClient(User user){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_ID,user.getUserId());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME,user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER,user.getNumber());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_GENDER,user.getGender());
        values.put(COLUMN_AMOUNT,user.getAmount());

        db.insert(TABLE_CLIENT,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

I want to know how to add the table with this in the existing database. 
It includes some upgrade section to be modified and I am not able to find it. I am new to android and not able to search for the correct code to modify it.

The error which I got is that Table clients is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting (will get) table not found is that a database is stored on disk aka it is persistent. It gets created once. Once it does exist then it doesn't get re-created. As such (unlike say an activity) the **onCreate** method only runs once for the lifetime of the database (unless otherwise called e.g. you will often see it called from the onUpgrade method).

As such you have to design the use of **onCreate** accordingly.

In your case perhaps the simplest way would be to combine the two classes e.g.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; //<<<<<<<<<< Changed so will call onUpgrade
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "manager.db";
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER = "user_mobile_number";

    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT, "+  COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT" + ")";

    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;


    private final static String TABLE_CLIENT = "clients";
    private final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    //private final static String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private final static String CLIENT_USER_ID = "client_user_id";
    private final static String COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME = "name";
    private final static String COLUMN_CLIENT_GENDER = "gender";
    private final static String COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_number";
    private final static String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public final static int GENDER_UNKNOWN = 0;
    public final static int GENDER_MALE = 1;
    public final static int GENDER_FEMALE = 2;

    private String CREATE_CLIENT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CLIENT + "( "
            + CLIENT_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_CLIENT_GENDER + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER" + " )";

    private String DROP_CLIENT_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CLIENT;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CLIENT_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DROP_CLIENT_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME,user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD,user.getPassword());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER,user.getNumber());

        db.insert(TABLE_USER,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password){
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ? ";
        String[] selectionArgs = {email , password};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null );

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if(cursorCount > 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email){
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" ;
        String[] selectionArgs = {email};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null );

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if(cursorCount > 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<String> getContactNumber(String email){
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] contact = new String[]{email};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER +", " + COLUMN_USER_ID + ", " +COLUMN_USER_NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " =?";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, contact);

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            a.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER)));
            a.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NAME)));
            a.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID)));

        }

        db.close();
        c.close();
        return a;
    }

    public boolean checkUserMobile(String contact){
        String[] columns = {
                CLIENT_USER_ID
        };

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER  + " =? ";
        String[] selectionArgs = {contact};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CLIENT,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null );

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if(count > 0){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addClient(User user){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_ID,user.getUserId());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME,user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE_NUMBER,user.getNumber());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_GENDER,user.getGender());
        values.put(COLUMN_AMOUNT,user.getAmount());

        db.insert(TABLE_CLIENT,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

- Note the comment //<<<<<<<<<< Changed so will call onUpgrade

  - This as it says will result in the onUpgrade method being called that drops both tables (now) and the calls onCreate which then creates both tables.
  - If you don't want to increase the Database version (e.g. like to keep it at 1 while developing the app) then, assuming that you have no data to be kept, you can delete the App's data or uninstall the App and rerun.
  - If you need to keep existing data then you' d need to ask another question, as that would be outside the scope of this question (viable though).
- You may notice that the line `//private final static String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";` has been commented out, this was because `COLUMN_USER_ID` was defined in both the original classes.
- Note that both the onUpgrade and onCreate methods have been altered to accommodate both tables.

Comment: OnUpgrade drops a table, so whether the data stored in the table will be lost or will remain.

Comment: @PriyanshuVaya yes Dropping tables will result in any data in the table being lost. , but onUpgrade doesn't have to drop tables and call onCreate, it could just create the second table i.e. just have `db.execSQL(CREATE_CLIENT_TABLE);` in it

Comment: Thanks @MikeT. I have one other query. I have listed on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513105/log-statement-giving-error-on-printing-the-value-of-intent-in-android